# User one @Pipe for two treatment

Tags: html, angular, pipe, ngfor

I would like to create a simple table with  the name of my items, a column that would take the "key" config and finally on the same line the values ​​associated with "key" and `<th>`.

But I use a @Pipe to filter my keys by removing the duplicates but I do not see how to bind the values ​​associated with the keys.

Here is my code hoping that my explanation is correct

config.json :

```html
[ { "id": "dev",
    "values": [ { 
      "name": "password",
      "value": "root-default://dev" },
      
      { "name": "env",
        "value": "env-default://dev" },
        
       { "name": "user",
         "value": "toto-default://dev" },
         
       { "name": "element",
          "value": "element-default://dev" } 
        ] },
      
      { "id": "test",
        "values": [ { 
        "name": "password",
        "value": "root-default://test" },
        
       { "name": "env",
         "value": "env-default://test" },
         
       { "name": "user",
         "value": "toto-default://test" },
         
       { "name": "element",
         "value": "element-default://test" } 
        ] },
        
       { "id": "toto",
        "values": [ {
          "name": "password",
          "value": "root-default://toto" },
          
          { "name": "env",
            "value": "env-default://toto" },
            
          { "name": "user",
            "value": "toto-default://toto" },
            
          { "name": "element",
            "value": "element-default://toto" } 
           ] }
 ]
```

My Html :

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="service && config">
  <table style="color: white; background-color: red;">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th *ngFor="let item of service.configs">{{item.name}}</th>
    </tr>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let key of (config | keys); let i = index">
        <tr>
          <td>{{key}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
  </table>
</ng-container>
```

My @Pipe:

```js
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any) {
        let listConf = [];
        let result = [];
        if(! value){
            return result;
        }

        for (let obj in value){
            let item = value[obj];
            if (result.indexOf(item.values) < 0) {
                listConf.push(item.values);
            }
        }

        for (let values in listConf) {
            let value = listConf[values];

            for (let items in value) {
                let item = value[items];
                if (result.indexOf(item.name) < 0) {
                    result.push(item.name);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

For the display of the `<th>` I use another object "service" which lists the names of the config

Service.json

```html
{ 
  "configs": [ 
      {"name": "dev"},  
      {"name": "test"},
      {"name": "toto"} 
  ]
}
```

My question is: how to have an array of key and an array of values ​​in the same @Pipe

My result with this code :

[Result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MP0N.png)

Comment: Hello @Mattis.h, sorry but your request is not clear.
Could you show us what is the expected result please ? (what should be displayed in the header of the table,ect..)

Comment: I added an image with the result of the table. I want fill in the rest of the table

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by completing the way you display your data in your view.

For example:

```html
<table>
        <tr>
           <th></th>
           <ng-container *ngFor="let item of config">
              <th>
                  {{item.id}}
              </th>
           </ng-container>
        </tr>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let key of (config | keys); let i = index">
            <tr>
               <td>{{key}}</td>
               <td>{{config[0].values[i].value}}</td>
               <td>{{config[1].values[i].value}}</td>
               <td>{{config[2].values[i].value}}</td>
            </tr>
         </ng-container>
   </table>
```

With this i get this result:
[image]

Edit: this solution works only if you respect the order of the column at generation as i hardcoded the index of columns in the second ngFor